Having trouble duplicating a model
I'm very new to blender and am trying to set up a scene.
I downloaded a model of a TV and am trying to duplicate it. When I click on it and press shift + D or Ctrl + C, then Ctrl + V it doesn't duplicate. Instead it seems to duplicate something that look likes points inside the model.
Here's the model:

Here's what it looks like when I duplicate it. That small red dot is the duplicated object
:

Looking at the scene collection, it looks like only one vertex (?) is being copied. I have no issues with copying basic stuff like cubes, so I'm guessing this is because it's a complex model. It seems like I'm missing something here.
Here's what it looks like inside the scene collection:

Can anyone advise how to duplicate the whole object?
Thank you.

what you show seems to be the origin, so probably you haven't selected the tv object but an object that has no mesh inside, but maybe share your file?

@moonboots Just tried to share it via blend exchange but it says the file's too big unfortunately - think it's because of the TV object. Is there an easy way to make sure I select the whole thing? Right click and selecting it seems to have the same issue.

use another platform like workupload then?

@moonboots Why? It's clear from the Outliner. The TV model seems to be consisting of 9 mesh objects parented to an empty and also 11 empties parented to the main empty. Only the main empty waa duplicated. hobbesedits: To make sure you select them all you should box select them, not just left-click on one of them. and probably use X-Ray mode as well. Or right-click on the parent in the Outliner and choose Select Hierarchy. But if you do not know how to select multiple objects, or what parenting and empties etc. are I would highly recommend you start learning the basics in Blender.

The weird thing is that he is unable to select the TV object, instead he duplicates an empty or an empty object? not sure to understand...

@GordonBrinkmann Thank you! Selecting everything in X-ray mode let me select everything, along with selecting the hierarchy.

In the Outliner, right click on the "Bottom Left" empty object > Select Hierarchy.
Then in the 3D window press Shift D to create a copy, or Alt D to create a Linked copy (a copy that share the same object data, so that if you edit one object, all copies get the same edit).

